# Adjust projection of 3d plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Matlab doesn't have an easy off-the-shelf way to adjust the distortion of the projection's perspective of a 3D figure that I know of. So, given the code below:

```
figure;
x1 = rand(1,10);
x2 = rand(1,10);
x3 = rand(1,10);
scatter3(x1,x2,x3,80,'o','filled'); hold on
ax = gca;
ax.Projection='perspective';
```

the results is unimpressive:

[image]

I tried modifying `ax.CameraTarget`, the `ax.CameraPosition`, etc. but the it's nearly impossible to modify the "vanishing point" to look more distorted, e.g. like this:
[image]

Any help as to how to achieve this level of control on the figure appearance?

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by moving into the "wide angle" regime, i.e. choosing a large `CameraViewAngle` while moving the camera further towards the plot. That gives you quite some distortion, like you might know from wide angle camera lenses.

In the following code, I assumed that the camera is placed at the center `z`-level of the coordinate system and `x` and `y`-coordinates are displaced just at the connection line between two edge points of the coordinate system being back-shifted by its length. The rest is basically "law of cosines". Feel free to adapt the camera position within the given sensible levels, such that the view angle remains in the range between 0 and 180 degrees, https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.axis.axes-properties.html#budumk7-View). This example assumes that the view angle in the `x`-`y`-plane is about the same as in the `y`-`z`-plane. Otherwise one would need to extend the calculation and take the average or maximum angle of both.

```matlab
figure;
x1 = rand(1, 10) + 10;
x2 = rand(1, 10) + 15;
x3 = rand(1, 10) + 10;
scatter3(x1, x2, x3, 80, 'o', 'filled');

% get the axis limits
xax = xlim; yax = ylim; zax = zlim;

ax = gca;
ax.Projection = 'perspective';

% get the default camera target (where the cam looks at)
camTarget = get(ax, 'CameraTarget');

newCamPos = [ 2*xax(1)-xax(2) 2*yax(1)-yax(2) camTarget(3) ];
a = sqrt((xax(1)-newCamPos(1))^2 + (yax(2)-newCamPos(2))^2);
b = sqrt((xax(2)-newCamPos(1))^2 + (yax(1)-newCamPos(2))^2);
lsqr = (xax(2)-xax(1))^2 + (yax(2)-yax(1))^2;
angle = acos((lsqr - a^2 - b^2) / -(2*a*b)) *180/pi;

set(ax, 'CameraViewAngle', angle, ...
        'CameraPosition', newCamPos);
```

[image: Sketch of lengths and points that are used in the matlab code]

Comment: Great! but the solution seems particular to the limits I provided? For example, how would be the value for CameraViewAngle and CameraPosition for the following situation (or another one?). Thanks a lot! 
x1 = randi([1 9],10);
x2 = randi([5 18],10);
x3 = rand(1,10);
scatter3(x1,x2,x3,80,'o','filled')

Comment: You are right. I just generalized a bit and edited my previous answer accordingly.